# angular ng-model transclude transfer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create custom elements which will convert my form elements to match bootstrap's form styling structure

Basically,

```
<my-input ng-model="myname">
```

should become

```
<div class="form-element">
    <input ng-model="myname" />
</div>
```

The problem is that when I use transclude, the ng-model goes to the root element and the resulting DOM is

```
<div class="form-element" ng-model="myname">
    <input>
</div>
```

Is it possible to choose which inner element the ng-model attribute is transferred to??

If I create another directive called my-model and use it instead of ng-model, how can I transfer this to the inner input element?

```
<my-input my-model="myname">
```

should become

```
<div class="form-element">
    <input ng-model="myname" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is unnecessary to use ng-transclude here, you can simply have directive

```
<my-input model="myname">
```

and directive template

```
<div class="form-element">
    <input ng-model="model" />
</div>
```

where directives scope is

```
scope: {
    'model': '='
}
```

By using this you can have couple of models in directive and you can put them wherever you want.

Comment: I want to use model as a directive and not as an attribute because many of my other custom directive will use this syntax and i don't want to bring in model everytime with isolated scope.

Comment: Then adding ng-transclude on input itself might work
`<my-input ng-model="myname">`
and directive template
`<div class="form-element">
<input ng-transclude />
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I ran into this issue a little while ago.
You need to bind your ng-model as a property of an object such as.

```
<div class="form-element">
<input ng-model="user.myname" />
</div>
```

And in controller, make sure you do this.

```
$scope.user = {};
```

In this way, angular would be able to find the ng-model.